# elements of arraylist duplicated

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

i have created an arraylist and added elements (string array) to it in a DO While loop. i use the following to add the elements:

```
tempList.add(recordArray); //- recordArray is a String[]

//ArrayList<String[]> tempList = new ArrayList<String[]>();// is declared in the activity before onCreate method
```

if i check the array within the DO WHILE loop using following code:

```
aStringArray = tempList.get(index);
Log.i(TAG,"aStringArray[0] = " + aStringArray[3]);
index++;
```

i get the correct string for each of the 3 array elements added to the arrayList.

the problem is when i try using the same code outside of the DO WHILE loop, the same string is displayed for each of the 3 iterations.

so to sum up, in the DO WHILE loop i get the following:

```
1st iteration -  aStringArray[3] - displays "100350
2nd iteration -  aStringArray[3] - displays "100750
3rd iteration -  aStringArray[3] - displays "100800
```

outside of the DO WHILE loop i get the following:

```
1st iteration -  aStringArray[3] - displays "100800
2nd iteration -  aStringArray[3] - displays "100800
3rd iteration -  aStringArray[3] - displays "100800
```

i've searched all over for an answer but can't find one. hope someone here can help.

much appreciated

clive

Comment: Can you post the code? I can't really follow what you're saying here.

Comment: Can you give us the **specific** code you are using outside the loop to display those iterations?

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suspect you're adding the *same* string array each time you go through the loop. You should create a *new* string array each time.

Don't forget that the list only contains *references*. So my guess is that your code looks like this:

```
ArrayList<String[]> tempList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String[] recordArray = new String[4];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    recordArray[0] = "a" + i;
    recordArray[1] = "b" + i;
    recordArray[2] = "c" + i;
    recordArray[3] = "d" + i;
    tempList.add(recordArray);
}
```

That ends up with an `ArrayList` of 10 identical references. Instead, you want this:

```
ArrayList<String[]> tempList = new ArrayList<String[]>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    String[] recordArray = new String[4];
    recordArray[0] = "a" + i;
    recordArray[1] = "b" + i;
    recordArray[2] = "c" + i;
    recordArray[3] = "d" + i;
    tempList.add(recordArray);
}
```

That way you have references to 10 *different* arrays in the list.

Comment: thank you very much. that was my problem. i was totally confused by the fact that when i try and extract the strings from the list whithin the Do-WHILE loop it worked perfectly yet when i use the same loop to extract the strings but outside of the DO-WHILE loop, i got the same string over and over. thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted your code so I have to guess, but it sounds like you're adding the same `String[]` to your list multiple times and just modifying that single array instance on each iteration of your loop.

You need to make sure that you actually allocate a new array on each iterations. eg: there should be a line something like:

```
recordArray = new String[size];
```

inside your loop.

Comment: thank you very much. that was my problem. i changed my code and it's working perfectly. thanks again