# get duplicated elements in Vector after multiple add

Tags: java, vector

In a loop I am trying to create a new Object and add it to an existing Vector, but at each iteration the previous elements changes and all of them become finally the same. The last one is replicated. It's like if I was creating the same Object, or giving the same reference. But I create a new Object at each iteration (well, I guess).

```
 static Vector myclients = new Vector();//note : this is an attribute of 
  //the all class, not just of that method, and I call those methods 
  // from the main of the same class

while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {

      if ( strLine.length() != 0 &&
           ! strLine.trim().substring(0,1).trim().equals("#")){
        // splitting my string
        String[] result = strLine.trim().split("\\s+");
        int codigo = new  Integer (Integer.parseInt(result[0].trim()) ) ;
        String nome = new String (result[1].trim() );

        try{
          if (result[2].trim().equals("cliente")){
            Cliente newcliente = new Cliente(codigo, nome);                
            Interface.err("Before addElement : "+myclientes.toString());
            myclientes.addElement(newcliente);
            Interface.err("after : "+myclientes.toString() );

          }else if (){
            // quite the same                 
          }

        }catch(Exception e){
          Interface.err("pb ... : "+e);
        }

      } // if 
    } // while
```

My Client class has got a lot of static elements :

```
public class Client {
  public static Integer code;
  public static String name;
  Client(){
     code = null;
     name = "undefined";
  }

  Client(Integer code, String name){
    this.code = code;
    this.name = name;
  }
```

}

And what I get is :

```
Before addElement : []
after : [Vincent 0]
Before addElement : [emilie 999]
after : [emilie 999, emilie 999]
Before addElement : [vince 5, vince 5]
after : [bob 5, bob 5, bob 5]
```

There's kind of the same question here
[elements of arraylist duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626587/elements-of-arraylist-duplicated)
but it didn't help me ...

Thanks for your help !

ps : I just tried building a new Integer and String for code and name, but apparently that changes nothing.

Comment: How does the Client class constructor look like?

Comment: Show the rest of your code - at least to the end of the loop

Comment: Show your Client class - the loop looks fine. (Not seeing the Client class, Laurence's answer looks like a good guess.)

Comment: `Vector` is for all practical purposes `deprecated` use a `List` instead, if you have books or tutorials telling you to use `Vector`, `Hashtable` or `Enumeration` throw them out, if you have an instructor telling you to use these classes, quit their class.

Comment: Show the code for the `Client` class.

Comment: Woops, thx I didn't know that. I spoke about the vector with my teacher and he didn't tell me ! (added some more code)

Answer (score 3):

Since you're creating a new Client object each time it looks like the fields in Client may be static when they shouldn't be.

Comment: And they are ! wooops, I had already noticed but it's creating more problems than I thought ... (posting some more code)

Comment: So I guess my project is badly designed, for I use the myclients Vector in the main class (--> need of static) which calls the above code (in other methods of the same class) (--> and finally get static pbs).